# Labeling MGRS grid indeces in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mgrs

I am trying to label the 1000m MGRS lines on my custom 24k maps, using QGIS. I know that I need to use a custom expression to do this but can't figure out how to write it to get them to look like this (which is easy in ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap, but I only have that at work).
[image]

I used these expressions individually, on two separate grids (10k and 1000m)

> left( right( @grid_number, 5), 2)

and

> left( right( @grid_number, 7), 2)

to get this far, but cannot combine them into one expression, with the different font sizes.
[image]

I have followed the Klas Karlsson video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2tVai2Ubzo), but get an error "no feature found.." even though you can see that the grid does have a 0 values for the IF statement (see map grid behind the expression box).

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas, or see something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check Klas Karlsson yt tutorial. He explains in depth how you can do it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlOx_E-odg8&t=2292s